# One x axis, one y axis on left, one y axis on right

Tags: python, matplotlib

With pandas, it's possible to plot 2 series on one single figure, with :

```
Y1.plot()
Y2.plot(secondary_y=True)
```

It gives:

- one common x-axis
- one y-axis on left for `Y1`
- one y-axis on right for `Y2`

**How to do the same with matplotlib only (not using pandas)?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`twinx`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.twinx). See the [example here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html).

Simply:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,ax1 = plt.subplots(1)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax1.plot([0,1,2,3,4],[0,1,2,3,4],'ro-')
ax2.plot([0,1,2,3,4],[400,300,200,100,0],'b-')

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Edit, You can achieve this without the object-oriented approach (`fig,ax`, etc.). Calling `plt.twinx` after the first plotting function will create the new twin Axes, which subsequent plotting events will be plotted on

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([0,1,2,3,4],[0,1,2,3,4],'ro-')
plt.twinx()
plt.plot([0,1,2,3,4],[400,300,200,100,0],'b-')
```

This does remove all the benefits of the OO approach though, and it becomes less clear which axes you will be plotting on, etc.

Comment: Great! Is it possible with shorter code, without `fig,ax1 = plt.subplots(1)
` ?

Comment: sure, see my edit. You do lose a lot of convenience doing it that way though